# Display a category only when it has posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, sticky, wordpress-featured-image

For many different reasons I was forced to deactivate the sticky posts function on WordPress. Still I need this function. This means that I need a workaround. I need to show a post on the top of the feed and I need it to be made as easily as possible for the user that is writing the post.

NOTE: I am using Visual Composer.

I thought that a workaround for this would be to add a new container via Visual Composer or a sidebar and call for a category. This new sidebar/container would then only be visible if there were any posts on that category. I have been searching for a function, query, plugin, etc to do this, but with no success.

I have found [Featured Post Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-feature-widget/screenshots/) and [Featured Category Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-feature/screenshots/) but I don't think that they are what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Hook with **`get_terms`** will display a **terms/category** only when it has posts

Add this code in WP theme's `functions.php`

E.g **(domain.com/wp-content/themes/yourThemeName/functions.php )**

```
add_filter('get_terms', 'get_terms_filter', 10, 3);
function get_terms_filter( $terms, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomy = $taxonomies[0];
    if ( ! is_array($terms) && count($terms) < 1 )
        return $terms;
    $filtered_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts p JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships rl ON p.ID = rl.object_id WHERE rl.term_taxonomy_id = $term->term_id AND p.post_status = 'publish' LIMIT 1");
        if ( intval($result) > 0 )
            $filtered_terms[] = $term;
    }
    return $filtered_terms;
}
```

For ignore sticky posts on frontend set `ignore_sticky_posts` to `true` in main query

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', '_ignore_sticky');

function _ignore_sticky($query)
{
    // Only for Front end
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query())
        $query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you did understand me. The Ignore sticky posts is already on and that is what is causing the problem. Where would I insert the code you supply?

Comment: @viriato you asked for `Display a category only when it has posts` and for ingore stick post `I need this due to different factors but we can start from the point that I needed WP to ignore sticky posts.`, if you want to show sticky posts you can change this `$query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', true);` to this `$query->set('ignore_sticky_posts', false);`

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I explained myself in a wrong way. The sticky posts are already being ignored due to many factors, so I need a workaround for this. Do you wish me to explain it in other way? Feel free to ask me questions...

Comment: what u actually want to do with sticky posts and what will happen if you create sticky post with featured category ? what you actually want to do with that? explain your criteria in question using `Edit`